# Trefoil knot as an algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-curves, knot-theory

Is the [trefoil knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot) with its usual embedding into affine $3$-space

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot]

an algebraic curve (maybe after extending scalars to $\mathbb{C}$)? Is there even some thickening to some algebraic surface? If not, is there at least some similar algebraic curve which describes this type of knot? I hope that this question is not silly, I know almost nothing about this classical stuff on algebraic curves. A google research indicates that there is some connection with the cusp $y^2=x^3$, but I don't really get it.

PS: I am interested in explicit equations. Specifically, is the trefoil cut out by two equations in affine $3$-space?

Comment: Analytic parametrizations can be also found on wikipedia; I am looking for an implicit definition given by a polynomial ( = algebraic curve). Agol's answer refers to the cusp, hm ...

Comment: @Martin: Wikipedia says, "In algebraic geometry, the trefoil can also be obtained as the intersection in $\mathbb{C}^2$ of the unit 3-sphere $S^3$ with the complex plane curve of zeroes of the complex polynomial $z^2 + w^3$ (a cuspidal cubic)."

Comment: For the curve, it seems like you should be able to find an easy algebraization from its characterization as the (3,2) torus knot; if you're interested in an implicit characterization for a thickened surface then it seems at least at first glance like level sets of that algebraic version should get the job done, though admittedly I haven't plugged through the math to try this...

Comment: @Zhen: It would be great if someone can expand this is an answer (and derive some equation from it).

Comment: See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197639 . I might come over here and write a longer answer if I get a chance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [paper](http://data.imaginary-exhibition.com/IMAGINARY-Trefoil-Stephan-Klaus.pdf) of Stephan Klaus that gives an explicit algebraic surface construction of the solid trefoil.

In addition, I found part of a [solution](http://books.google.com/books?id=3OtUpdFiXvkC&pg=PA321&lpg=PA321&dq=trefoil+knot+implicit+function&source=bl&ots=hQEY5fJfYW&sig=M8BNeIYqL-ggmlT8gCVPOuBfRMc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yjK9T9nFMsOA2wXJi4mbDw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=trefoil%20knot%20implicit%20function&f=false) to finding an algebraic curve isotopic to the trefoil by Michael Trott, but unfortunately the final pages are missing from the Google Books preview.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Perhaps someone can add the formula which is only partially visible in the google books preview.

Comment: Here is the equation of the terfoil surface for copy & paste in SURFER or other visualization software: (-8*(x^2 + y^2)^2*(x^2 + y^2 + 1 + z^2 + a^2 - b^2) + 4*a^2*(2*(x^2 + y^2)^2 -(x^3 - 3*x*y^2)*(x^2 + y^2 + 1)) + 8*a^2*(3*x^2*y - y^3)*z + 4*a^2*(x^3 - 3*x*y^2)*z^2)^2 -(x^2 + y^2)*(2*(x^2 + y^2)*(x^2 + y^2 + 1 + z^2 + a^2 - b^2)^2 + 8*(x^2 + y^2)^2 +4*a^2*(2*(x^3-3*x*y^2)-(x^2+y^2)*(x^2+y^2+1))-8*a^2*(3*x^2*y-y^3)*z-4*(x^2+y^2)*a^2*z^2)^2

Answer (score 16):

Consider two relatively prime integers $p,q \geq 2$ and the complex affine curve $C\subset \mathbb C^2 $given by $x^p+y^q=0$, which has an isolated singularity at the origin $O=(0,0)$.

If  $C$ is intersected with the real $3$-sphere $S_\epsilon$ of equation $\mid x\mid ^2+\mid y \mid^2=\epsilon ^2$,  Brauner proved in 1928 that the  resulting real algebraic curve $C\cap S_\epsilon$ is a $(p,q)$ knot.
For $p=2, q=3$ , you obtain the trefoil knot, as you correctly conjectured.

Milnor has written a fantastic booklet (122 pages...) on the subject: *Singular points of complex hypersurfaces*, published by Princeton in 1968, with   Brauner's theorem
 proved on the second page!

**Edit**
The intersection $C\cap S_\epsilon\subset \mathbb C^2=\mathbb R^4$ is a *real* algebraic curve with completely explicit polynomial equations .
For the trefoil knot with $p=2,q=3 $ for example, we get (writing $x=x_1+ix_2, y=y_1+iy_2$)
$$ x_1^2+x_2^2+y_1^2+y_2^2=\epsilon^2, \quad  x_1^2-x_2^2+y_1^3-3y_1y^2_2=0,\quad 2x_1x_2+3y_1^2y_2-y_2^3=0      $$

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I am mistaken, but $S_{\epsilon}$ doesn't seem to be an algebraic subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$. Or is the ground field still $\mathbb{R}$? Also, does this yield an explicit equation?

Comment: Dear Martin, yes, I meant *real* algebraic subset. I have written an edit.

Comment: Alright. So this cuts out the trefoil in $\mathbb{R}^4$ using three equations. I would like to know if it is possible to cut it out in $\mathbb{R}^3$ via one equation.

Comment: Dear Martin, sure, you can sum the squares of any number of equations defining a curve (or, for that matter, any real algebraic variety) and get one equation, but this is rather meaningless. You can't hope to define a curve in $\mathbb R^3$ in a serious way by just one equation.

Comment: Ok, that's true. What about two equations in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Dear Martin, I have tried to answer your original question and some in the comments as best I could. I am sure you have many other interesting questions, but I suggest you ask them in new posts.

Answer (score 11):

I know I am a bit late, but I think it is pretty easy to see that the trefoil can be described in terms of algebraic equations. Consider the parametrization from Wikipedia:
$$
x = \sin t + 2 \sin 2t, \quad y=\cos t - 2 \cos 2t, \quad z=-\sin 3t.
$$
Using the rules for double and triple angle this is equal to
$$
x = \sin t + 4 \sin t\cos t, \quad y=\cos t - 2 +4\sin^2 t, \quad z=-\sin t (4\cos^2 t -1).
$$
Denoting $s=\sin t$ and $c=\cos t$ you have the ideal
$$
I=\langle s + 4 sc-x,c - 2 +4s-y,-s (4c -1)-z,s^2+c^2-1\rangle
$$
describing the trefoil. The equation $s^2+c^2-1=0$ makes the connection between $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ while eliminating the parameter $t$. Now you can eliminate $s$ and $c$ in order to obtain a representation in the variables $x,y$ and $z$. Here is the [SINGULAR](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de) code:

```
ring R = 0,(x,y,z,s,c),dp;
ideal I = 4*s*c-x+s, 4*s^2-y+c-2, -4*s*c^2-z+s, s^2+c^2-1;
ideal J = eliminate(I,sc);
```

Now $J=\langle P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6\rangle$ with
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_1&=12x^2y-4y^3-13x^2-13y^2+64z^2+9,\\
P_2&=x^3-3xy^2+4x^2z+4y^2z-9z,\\
P_3&=64y^3z+9x^3+9xy^2+4x^2z+100y^2z-192xz^2\\
&\phantom{=}-256z^3-72xy-180yz+27x-36z,\\
P_4&=256xy^2z-256x^2z^2-256y^2z^2-16y^3-128xyz\\
&\phantom{=}+256yz^2+35x^2-61y^2-240xz+640z^2-36y+9,\\
P_5&=48y^4+112y^3-144xyz-192yz^2-35x^2\\
&\phantom{=}-143y^2-108xz-160z^2-108y+99,\\
P_6&=8xy^3-4x^3+8xy^2-24x^2z-32xz^2-18xy-18yz+9x+27z.
\end{aligned}
$$
Maybe there are also generators with smaller degree. I haven't tried to find them yet.

There is also the famous trick to generate a single equation for the space curve:
$$
T=\sum_{i=1}^6 P_i^2.
$$
Over the real numbers you have $V_\mathbb{R}(J)=V_\mathbb{R}(T)$.

I'd like to post an image of a visualization based on the algebraic equations. But unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet.

**Edit:** Now I have enough reputation to post an image:

[image]

Comment: I wrote an answer on MO heavily based on this one. https://mathoverflow.net/a/281629/

Answer (score 11):

Another answer to this question, based on ideas from my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197639/find-f-such-that-f-1-lbrace0-rbrace-is-this-knotted-curve-m-w-hirsh). I will write a trefoil knot as the transverse intersection of two smooth polynomial surfaces. I will also draw pictures!

Here is the basic idea. Let $S^3$ be the sphere $|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = 2$ inside $\mathbb{C}^2$. I'll write each coordinate $z_j$ as $x_j+i y_j$. The trefoil knot $K$ is given by the equation $z_1^3 = z_2^2$ in $S^2$. Taking real and imaginary parts, we get
$$x_1^3 - 3 x_1^2 y_1 = x_2^2 - y_2^2 \qquad 3 x_1^2 y_1 - y_1^3 = 2 x_2 y_2. \qquad (1)$$
I compute in my linked answer that these give smooth, transverse, surfaces in $S^3$.

That's $S^3$, but the OP asked for $\mathbb{R}^3$. To this end, we can remove a point from $S^3$. Since the OP wants a closed knot, not one that goes off to infinity, we should remove a point not on $K$. It is also good to remove a point where $z_1^3-z_2^2$ is neither purely real nor purely imaginary, so the two 
surfaces in $(1)$ will stay compact. I choose the point $(1+i, 0)$.

Stereographic projection away from the point $(1+i, 0)$ is given by the formula
$$(u,v,w) \ = \ \frac{1}{2-x_1-y_1} (x_1-y_1, x_2, y_2) \qquad (2).$$
Composing $(2)$ with the parametrization $(e^{2 i t}, e^{3 i t})$ of $K$, we get a knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized as
$$\left( \frac{\cos (2 t) - \sin(2 t)}{2-\sin (2 t)-\cos (2 t)},\
\frac{\cos (3 t)}{2-\sin (2 t)-\cos (2 t)},\
\frac{\sin (3 t)}{2-\sin (2 t)-\cos(2 t)}\right).$$

[image: Rotating image of trefoil knot]

To get equations for the surfaces in $(1)$, we need to have the inverse of $(2)$. That's easy to compute; the inverse map is
$$(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)  = $$
$$\frac{1}{u^2+2 v^2+2 w^2+1} \left( u^2+2 u+2 v^2+2 w^2-1,\
u^2-2 u+2 v^2+2 w^2-1,\
4v,\ 4 w \right). $$
Plugging this into $(1)$ and putting everything over a common denominator, we get the equations
$$2 + 12 u - 30 u^2 - 40 u^3 + 30 u^4 + 12 u^5 - 2 u^6 - 28 v^2 - 
 48 u v^2 + 56 u^2 v^2 + 48 u^3 v^2 - 12 u^4 v^2 - 8 v^4 + 48 u v^4 - 
 24 u^2 v^4 - 16 v^6 + 4 w^2 - 48 u w^2 + 88 u^2 w^2 + 48 u^3 w^2 - 
 12 u^4 w^2 + 48 v^2 w^2 + 96 u v^2 w^2 - 48 u^2 v^2 w^2 - 
 48 v^4 w^2 + 56 w^4 + 48 u w^4 - 24 u^2 w^4 - 48 v^2 w^4 - 16 w^6 =$$
$$-2 + 12 u + 30 u^2 - 40 u^3 - 30 u^4 + 12 u^5 + 2 u^6 + 12 v^2 - 
 48 u v^2 - 72 u^2 v^2 + 48 u^3 v^2 + 12 u^4 v^2 - 24 v^4 + 
 48 u v^4 + 24 u^2 v^4 + 16 v^6 - 32 v w - 32 u^2 v w - 64 v^3 w + 
 12 w^2 - 48 u w^2 - 72 u^2 w^2 + 48 u^3 w^2 + 12 u^4 w^2 - 
 48 v^2 w^2 + 96 u v^2 w^2 + 48 u^2 v^2 w^2 + 48 v^4 w^2 - 64 v w^3 - 
 24 w^4 + 48 u w^4 + 24 u^2 w^4 + 48 v^2 w^4 + 16 w^6=0$$
for $K$.

Here is the first equation, together with the knot. (Apologies for the gaps in the knot; I spent a while fighting with Mathematica and I want to go to bed. And thanks to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4537) for getting me this far!)

[image: surface and knot]

And here are the two surfaces together. It's hard for me to actually see this, but it is two genus two surfaces, meeting along the knot.

[image]

As a final note, I spent a long time trying to get $K$ as the intersection of a genus $1$ surface with something, since $K$ is, after all, a torus knot. It took me a while to understand why I was failing: If $K$ is to be the transverse intersection of $T$ and $\{ f=0 \}$, then I want $f$ restricted to $T$ to be positive on one side of $K$ and negative on the other. But, if I embed $K$ into a torus $T$, then $K$ will not disconnect $T$, so this is impossible. The knot $K$ does disconnect the genus $2$ surfaces in the pictures, which is why I succeed.

Answer (score 1):

See the following paper for lots of examples:

G. Freudenburg, "Bivariate analogues of Chebyshev polynomials with application to embeddings of affine spaces", CRM Proceedings and Lecture Notes, vol. 54 (2011), American Math. Society, 39-56.

GF

Answer (score 0):

It all seems rather complicated to me, but no doubt I've missed something.

I just used polar coordinates  $1/r = 1 + 0.5 \cos (3A/2)$.

This gives a lovely plane trefoil.  The cartesian equation has 11 terms & is of the sixth
degree in x & y - can give it if anyone interested

David R Roberts