# Find $f$ such that $f^{-1}(\lbrace0\rbrace)$ is this knotted curve (M.W.Hirsh)

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, knot-theory, submanifold

I would like to solve the following problem (it comes from Morris W. Hirsh, *Differential Topology*, it's exercise 6 section 4 chapter 1):

> Show that there is a $C^\infty$ map $f:D^3\to D^2$ with $0\in D^2$ as a regular value such that $f^{-1}(\lbrace0\rbrace)$ is a knotted curve (as in the picture below).
>   [image: Figure 1]

I have been thinking about this problem for a while but I still have no answer. Here is what I came up with so far: if there was no knot on the figure and we wanted $f^{-1}(\lbrace0\rbrace)$ to be a straight line from north to south pole, then $f$ exists, we can take $f$ to be the orthogonal projection onto $(z=0)$. If we do so, we could precompose $f$ by a diffeomorphism of $D^3$ taking the straight line to the knot on the figure, which would give the answer. But I am pretty sure that such a diffeomorphism doesn't exists (the fundamental group of the complement of both path are not isomorphic), and it would be what makes this exercise difficult.

I've been thinking about moving the path to get a better viewpoint, but it didn't succeed.

I am really intrigued by this question, I like it a lot because it doesn't seem right. I am not looking for a complete answer (yet), I just would like a hint to feel how somebody should approach this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**Edit:** As suggested by Laz in the comments, there might be an answer to this problem involving techniques such as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148916/trefoil-knot-as-an-algebraic-curve). The idea would be to construct $f$ with polynomial coefficients. 
I went back to read the introduction of the book and this is what M.W.Hirsh says: *"The more challenging exercises are starred, as are those requiring algebraic topology or other advanced topics."* (This is a one star exercise).

So maybe M.W.Hirsh thought about a solution involving polynomial equations etc, but I must admit I would be a bit disappointed in this case, I was hoping that there is a solution involving differential topology. For example I had the following idea: take a tubular neighborhood of the curve $K$, which looks like $I\times D^2$, and define $f$ on this neighborhood by the projection of the second factor. We could try to extend $f$ on $D^3$ (but I don't see how).

Anyway at that point any kind of answer (involving differential topology or not) would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit 2:** Many thanks to HerrWarum for the bounty.

Comment: OK, Adam, I posted an answer with some insights, but I went a little too far on the vagueness. I'll have to adjust it a bit, so it is ready to post.

Comment: Hi Laz, I just had the time to read it once I'll wait for your final answer to comment it, thanks for your help !

Comment: Adam, I have given some thought to this question, but I still don't have a rigorous proof. What I originally posted was along the fact that the Trefoil knot K is an algebraic curve. Now, I haven't been able to find two algebraic surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose intersection is K, and I need this fact because my proof was heavily based on this. There is some discussion here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148916/trefoil-knot-as-an-algebraic-curve. Anyway, what do you propose? We could discuss it, but definitely this question has not gotten a lot of attention ...

Comment: It is true, though, that K is an algebraic surface, it's just that in the literature I can only find it as the intersection of various polynomials in a lot more variables ...

Comment: Hi @Laz, again thank you for your time. Ok so in the link you gave, they express a thick treifol knot as the zero of a polynomial. Say we express the curve on my picture as the zero of a function $f$ with polynomial coefficients, by taking some inspiration from the link (which would take a huge amount of work I think). It is not clear that we can take $0$ to be a regular value for $f$. Also, even if $0$ is a regular value, this type of solution won't give me a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: In my opinion it would be pretty disappointing if M. Hirsh was thinking about this kind of approach to solve the problem. Even if there might be an answer involving algebraic curve/ knot theory, I would prefer something constructed "by hand" but from the viewpoint of a differential topologist (for example we could think about how $f$ extends on a tubular neighborhood of $f^{-1}(0)$ and maybe we could extend it to $D^3$?). I think I will start a bounty soon to get some attention on this question.

Comment: Adam, I do not have the time right now, but I think Exercise 12, page 28 of Hirsch's book solves your problem. Take a look ...

Comment: @Laz I took a look at exercise 12. I see it's related to the problem, but I don't see how it solves it unfortunately. Can you give a bit more details?

Comment: I don't know much about the subject - could you explain what \$D\$ is?

Comment: @flawr $D^n$ is the $n$-dimensional disc, the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Main construction**

Let $\gamma$ be the trefoil knot in $\mathbb{S}^3$. Since $\gamma$ is a fibered knot (see D. Rolfsen, Knots and Links, Chapters H and I), there is a tubular neighborhood $N\gamma \simeq \mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{D}^2$ and a fibration $f': \mathbb{S}^3\backslash\langle\gamma\rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{1}$ such that $$ f'(x,y) = \frac{y}{|y|}\quad\text{for all } (x,y)\in \mathbb{S}^1\times (\mathbb{D}^2\backslash\{0\}). $$
The projection to the second factor of $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{D}^2$ determines a smooth map $f'': N\gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{D}^2$ with regular value $0$ and with $(f'')^{-1}(0)=\langle\gamma\rangle$. We define $f: \mathbb{S}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{D}^2$ by 
$$f(z):=\begin{cases}
f''(z) &\text{for }z\in N\gamma, \text{ and by}\\
f'(z) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
The compatibility condition guarantees that $f$ is continuous. Notice that the entire complement of $N\gamma$ gets mapped into $\mathbb{S}^1 = \partial \mathbb{D}^2$.

**Some details**

**1)** Looking at the figure, we extend the curve through the boundary points outside of $\mathbb{D}^3$ and connect the two ends there to obtain the trefoil $\gamma: \mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. We then pick a smooth embedding $\psi: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^3$, transfer everything to $\mathbb{S}^3$, and construct $f: \mathbb{S}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{D}^2$. In the end, we consider the restriction $f\circ \psi: \mathbb{D}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{D}^2$.

**2)** The main construction gives a continuous extension $f: \mathbb{S}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{D}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of the smooth map $f'': N\gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{D}^2$ such that $f(\mathbb{S}^3 \backslash N\gamma)\subset \mathbb{S}^1$. To make $f$ smooth, we apply Theorem 2.5 from Chapter I of A. Kosinski, Differentiable manifolds:

*Theorem 2.5:* Let $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous map, smooth on a closed
subset $K$ of $M$, and let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there is a smooth map $g: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that agrees with $f$ on $K$ and such that $|f(p) - g(p)| < \varepsilon$ for all $p\in M$.

Applying this theorem to $f$, $M=\mathbb{S}^3$, $K=\frac{3}{4}N\gamma$, $n=2$ and $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, we obtain a smooth map $g: \mathbb{S}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ which equals $f$ on $K$ and such that $g^{-1}(0) = f^{-1}(0)$. Since $\mathbb{S}^3$ is compact, we can scale $g$ by a constant to achieve $g(\mathbb{S}^3)\subset \mathbb{D}^2$. The scaling changes neither the regularity of $0$ nor the level set $g^{-1}(0)$. This $g$, after the procedures from 1), is then the map $f$ we have been looking for.

**Acknowledgment**

The problem was solved with the help of Prof. Dr. Urs Frauenfelder who suggested to look in the Rolfsen's book for the precise definition of a fibered knot.

**Reaction to comments:**

@Moishe Kohan: It seems like that you are using a more general definition of a fibered knot where the compatibility condition does not necessarily hold, e.g., the definition from *J. Harer, How to construct all fibered knots.* This definition requires only that the complement $W:=M\backslash K$, where $M$ is a $3$-manifold and $K$ the knot, is a fibration over $\mathbb{S}^1$ such that closures of its fibers $F$ are Seifert surfaces. We then have $W\simeq F \times [0,1]/\sim$, where the ends are identified by a general homeomorphism $h$ of $F$. Then, of course, the intersection $F \cap N\gamma$, which is a knot itself, might link with $K$ non-trivially, depending on $h$.

However, the definition of a fibred knot from the Rolfsen's book, which I am using, imposes the compatibility condition, and hence link $link(F\cap N\gamma, K)=0$. This is a screenshot from the Rolfsen's book:

[image: Definition of a fibered knot from the Rolfsen's book]

A fibration of the trefoil satisfying this definition is constructed explicitly in Chapter I of the book.

According to your terminology, a fibration satisfying $link(F\cap N\gamma, K)=0$ is called a Seifert fibration. Hence, it seems like that Rolfsen defines and works with Seifert fibrations implicitly.

To complete the reply to your comment, I sum up the issue of the regular value here:

It holds $f^{-1}(0)=(f'')^{-1}(0)=\langle\gamma\rangle$ because the image of $f'$ lies inside of $\mathbb{S}^1$. Also, $0$ is a regular value of $f''$ since $f''$ is just a projection to the second component. It is also a regular value of $f$ as it agrees with $f''$ on a neighborhood of $\langle\gamma\rangle$. The smoothening of $f$ does not change these facts.

Comment: What you wrote is not enough: You need a fibration such that fibers (on the boundary of $N\gamma$) have linking number zero with the knot. (Otherwise when you construct your extension, the knot will not be the preimage of a regular value of the map: The issue you did not address at all in your answer.) In order to solve the problem you can use a different "fibration" (called a "Seifert fibration") where the given torus knot is a regular fiber.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback! I don't know much knot theory but I do like the Hirsch's book. Can you state precisely where the problem with my construction is? It holds $f^{-1}(0) = (f'')^{-1}(0) = \langle\gamma\rangle$ because the image of $f'$ lies in $\mathbb{S}^1$. Also, $0$ is a regular value because $f''$ is just the projection to the second component. The smoothening of $f$ does not change these facts.

Comment: The issue appears on the lines 2-3 of your answer where you describe the restriction  of the fibration on $S^3- \gamma$ to $N\gamma$.

Comment: I uploaded the definition from the Rolfsen's book. It seems identical with lines 2-3 except for exchanging "neighborhood framed as $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{D}^2$" for "tubular neighborhood". Is this the problem, what does the former notion means then?

Comment: @Pavel I see that you spent lots of time editing you question to make it better, thanks a lot for what you're doing! I have to reread it once or twice to make sure I fully understand. One thing that I definitely don't understand: why is $\gamma$ a fibered knot (I must say I have very little knowledge of knot theory)? Do you have a reference for that (preferably accessible for people like me)?

Comment: Dear Adam, yeah, I've been on it every free minute today, thanks for appreciation :-D I also do not know much knot theory but am motivated to learn more now. The fact that the trefoil is a fibered knot is proven in Chapter I of the Rolfsen's book. I should also study it in more in details; maybe I'll find out that my understanding is wrong (see Moishe Kohan''s comments).

Comment: With Rolfsen's definition your argument is just fine.

Answer (score 9):

An alternate, algebraic approach: Let $S^3$ be the sphere $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=2$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Then the trefoil knot $K$ is given by the equation $z_1^3 = z_2^2$ in $S^3$, and can be parametrized as $(e^{2 i \theta}, e^{3 i \theta})$. Define $\phi: S^3 \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\phi(z_1, z_2) = z_1^3 - z_2^2$. So $K = \phi^{-1}(0)$.

I claim that $\phi$ is a submersion along $K$. If we consider $\phi$ as a map $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$, it is a submersion everywhere except at $(0,0)$. To verify that it is still a submersion when restricted to $S^3$, we must check that the $2$-dimensional kernel of $D \phi$ is transverse to the $3$-dimensional tangent space to $S^3$ at every point of $K$. To do this, I just have to give an element of $\mathrm{Ker}(D \phi)$ which is not in $TS^3$. Namely, at the point $(e^{2 i \theta}, e^{3 i \theta})$, the vector $(2 e^{2 i \theta}, 3 e^{3 i \theta})$ is in $\mathrm{Ker}(D \phi)$ but not in $TS^3$. (We can think of this vector as the derivative of $(e^{2 (t+i \theta)}, e^{3 (t+i \theta)})$ with respect to $t$. This curve lies on $z_1^3=z_2^2$, so its derivative is in $\mathrm{Ker}(D \phi)$, but it is clearly transverse to $S^3$.)

So we have a $C^{\infty}$ map from $S^3$ to $\mathbb{C}$ where $\phi^{-1}(0)=K$ and $\phi$ is a submersion along $K$. To convert to a map $\mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, just remove a point from $S^3$: Remove a point on $K$ to make a knot which stretches off to infinity as in the diagram, or remove a point not on $K$ to make a closed knot.

Here is a picture of your knot, in stereographic projection from the point $(1,1) \in S^3$:

[image]

It can be given parametrically as
$$\left( \frac{\cos (2 t)-\cos (3 t)}{-\cos (2 t)-\cos (3 t)+2}, \
\frac{\sin (2 t)}{-\cos (2 t)-\cos (3 t)+2},\
\frac{\sin (3 t)}{-\cos (2 t)-\cos (3 t)+2}\right )$$

I get that the explicit coordinates of $\phi(u,v,w)$ are given by
$$\begin{multline} \frac{1}{(1 + u^2 + 2 v^2 + 2 w^2)^3} \\ \left(-2 + 2 u - 12 u^2 - 4 u^3 + 6 u^4 + 10 u^5 + 56 v^2 - 120 u v^2 - 
 40 u^2 v^2 + 40 u^3 v^2 - 104 v^4 + 40 u v^4 + 24 w^2 - 24 u w^2 + 
 24 u^2 w^2 + 40 u^3 w^2 - 80 v^2 w^2 + 80 u v^2 w^2 + 24 w^4 + 
 40 u w^4, \right. \\ \left. 12 v - 48 u v + 24 u^2 v + 48 u^3 v + 12 u^4 v - 112 v^3 + 96 u v^3 + 
 48 u^2 v^3 + 48 v^5 + 8 w + 16 u w + 16 u^3 w - 8 u^4 w + 
 32 u v^2 w - 32 u^2 v^2 w - 32 v^4 w - 48 v w^2 + 96 u v w^2 + 
 48 u^2 v w^2 + 96 v^3 w^2 + 32 u w^3 - 32 u^2 w^3 - 64 v^2 w^3 + 
 48 v w^4 - 32 w^5 \right)
\end{multline}$$
I got this by composing the inverse of sterographic projection,
$$\frac{1}{1+u^2+2 v^2+2 w^2} \left(u^2+2 u+2 v^2+2 w^2-1,4 v,u^2-2 u+2 v^2+2 w^2-1,4 w\right)$$
and the map $z_1^3 - z_2^2$.

Comment: Even if it is not really "in the spirit of M.W.Hirsh's book" I like this algebraic approach very much. Thanks a lot for your answer!